# Question about substitution in random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, substitution

The problem in question is the following:

```
Let X and Y be two independent random variables whose marginal PDFs are given below. Find the pdf of X+Y.
```

\begin{equation} 
f_X(x)=1, 0\leq x\leq 1\\  f_Y(y)=1, 0\leq y \leq 1
\end{equation}

My proposition is the following:

Let $w=x+y$ then the joint pdf of both variables will become:
\begin{equation}
f_w(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(w)f_Y(w-x)dx
\end{equation}
After we substitute $x$ for $w$ from the abovementioned conditions, we get that $0\leq w<1$ and for $f_Y:0<w-x<1\Longrightarrow x<w<1+x$ since $\max{x}=1$ and $\min{x}=0$ and because of this (I assume?) when we put this max-min back in the mentioned inequality we can get either $0<w<1$ or $1<w<2$ but I don't know whether that's the logic although that is at least how I understand it. For the case when $0\leq w<1$ the following integral $f_{X+Y}(w)=\int_0^1 1.1 dw$ is simple to derive, however, things get ridiculous when we consider the case when $1<w<2$ because then they write the following integral, in the solutions: $P_{X+Y}(w)=\int_{w-1}^{1}1.1dw$. So can someone please explain to me the logic behind all this because it seems I'm not really getting it?

Comment: First of all, the correct convolution formula should be $f_W(w) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(w - x)dx$.

Comment: I just was about to mention that as $w$ on the left side and as an integration variable is not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the correct convolution formula as I commented above, and notice that the integrand is non-zero if and only if $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq w - x \leq 1$, which implies that when $w > 2$ or $w < 0$ then $f_W(w) = 0$.  For $0 \leq w \leq 2$, the correct integration limits are then $\max(0, w - 1)$ and $\min(w, 1)$, which gives
\begin{align}
f_W(w) &= \int_{\max(0, w - 1)}^{\min(w, 1)} 1 \times 1 dx = \min(w, 1) - \max(0, w - 1) \\
&= \begin{cases}
w & 0 \leq w \leq 1, \\[1em]
2 - w & 1 < w \leq 2. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

To summarize, the density of $W$ is
\begin{align}
f_W(w) = \begin{cases}
w & 0 \leq w \leq 1, \\[1em]
2 - w & 1 < w \leq 2, \\[1em]
0 & w < 0 \text{ or } w > 2. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
You can verify that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_W(w) dw = 1$.

Alternatively (which I prefer, but for this problem may be more cumbersome than applying the convolution formula directly), $f_W$ can be determined by first calculating the distribution function $F_W$ of $W$ as follows:
\begin{align}
F_W(w) &= P[X + Y \leq w] = \int_0^1 P[x + Y \leq w]dx = \int_0^1P[Y \leq w - x]dx 
\\
&= \begin{cases}
0 & w < 0, \\[1em]
\int_0^w(w - x)dx & 0 \leq  w < 1, \\[1em]
\int_0^{w - 1} 1 dx + \int_{w - 1}^1 (w - x)dx & 1 \leq w < 2, \\[1em]
1 & w \geq 2. 
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
0 & w < 0, \\[1em]
\frac{1}{2}w^2 & 0 \leq  w < 1, \\[1em]
2w - \frac{1}{2}w^2 - 1 & 1 \leq w < 2, \\[1em]
1 & w \geq 2. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$f_W(w)$ can then be obtained by differentiating $F_W(w)$ with respect to $w$:
\begin{align}
f_W(w) = F_W'(w) = \begin{cases}
w & 0 \leq w < 1, \\[1em]
2 - w & 1 \leq w < 2, \\[1em]
0 & w < 0 \text{ or } w \geq 2. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the rigorous response but what I still don’t understand are the constraints of the intgral and why we have that it goes from $\max{0,w-1}$ to $\min{w,1}$

Comment: @СтойчоРобертовРусинов This has been clearly explained in the answer.  Let me put it in another way, given $1 \leq w \leq 2$, what if $x < \max(0, w - 1)$ or $x > \min(w, 1)$? Can you check what $f_X(x)f_Y(w - x)$ is under this condition?

Comment: I think that this min-max integration constraints are put in place in order to limit the $x$ to stay between 0 and 1 assuming changing $w$ because only then you can integrate with respect to x using the convolution formula!

Comment: @СтойчоРобертовРусинов You seem to get it partially.  I need to clarify that, $w$ is fixed (that is, we do not "changing $w$" in the process of doing integration), and integration limits are such that "to limit $x$ stay in the range so that the integrand $f_X(x)f_Y(w - x)$ is **non-zero**" (as opposed to "to limit $x$ to stay between $0$ and $1$").